# How to create multiple fields using REST query

Tags: rest, client-object-model

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600182(v=office.15).aspx), we can create field like below..

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
    /fields",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Field' }, 'Title': 'Comments', 'FieldTypeKind': 3 }",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

But question is how to create multiple fields with their datatypes. Like I want to create fields `EmpName` as `Single line of text`, `Department` as `lookup`, `Profile` as `Hyperlink`. How I can create metadata for all these fields?